# Why does SQLConfigDataSource fail?

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I have been given the task of migrating some C++ code to Win 10 that was written more than 10 years ago and the original developer is unreachable.

His code makes a call to

```
SQLConfigDataSource(NULL, ODBC_CONFIG_SYS_DSN, _T("Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)"), cfgs);
```

where cfgs is something like

```
const char *cfgs= 
"DSN=ExportBase\0"
"Drv=c:\\winnt\\system32\\odbcjt32.dll\0"
"DBQ=c:\\export\\exportbase.mdb\0"
"DriverId=25\0"
"FIL=MS Access;\0"
"PWD=password1\0"
"UID=Admin\0"
"SafeTrans=0\0\0";
```

The trouble is that this call does not succeed, and a call to SQLInstallerError to get the message returns a string like

> failure of ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver or ConfigTranslator of the driver.

(actually, I am translating this message from the French original).

I tried simplifying the string cfgs to a minimum:

```
"DSN=Database2\0UiD=Admin\0PWD=pWD\0DBQ=D:\\devt\\CPP\\MFC\\ODBCTest1\\Database2.mdb\0Drv=c:\\winnt\\system32\\odbcjt32.dll\0\0";
```

but even then the call fails.
However if I replace ODBC_CONFIG_SYS_DSN by ODBC_ADD_DSN and change the DSN name the call succeeds and creates a new datasource.

I must point out that:

1) I don't know why the previous developer called this function (the
   same effect could probably have been done with the ODBC Datasource
   Administrator).

2) I don't know exactly what the function is supposed
   to be doing in case of "update" anyway. What's being updated, what
   are the "key" fields?

3) It's not obvious that all attributes are relevant anyway.

4) The Microsoft doc on the subject is very terse.

Comment: What are you actually asking? You already have figured out you need to add the DSN before you can configure it (you can only configure an already created DSN).

Comment: I was maintaining a piece of software that only updated a DSN. No information on how it was created. I just found that out by experimenting. I know very little about ODBC.

Answer (score 2):

> The Microsoft doc on the subject is very terse.

If I read [sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlconfigdatasource-function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlconfigdatasource-function?view=sql-server-2017#comments) I see that it configs/creates `System-DSN`if it contains `_SYS_`as in `ODBC_CONFIG_SYS_DSN` but `User_DSN`without `_SYS_`like`ODBC_ADD_DSN`.

This app was writen to maybe`Windows XP`where usually users had admin-rights and were able to config/add the`System-DSN`. Nowadays users and their apps run with limited priviliges, what causes the app to fail. Start with admin-rights to config `System-DSN`or use `User-DSN`with`ODBC_CONFIG_DSN` instead of `ODBC_CONFIG_SYS_DSN`.

In addition, I assume your OS being x64, but the app to be x86(32-Bits), then keep in mind that an x86 app needs the DSN configured in `%Windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` not in `%Windir%\System32\odbcad32.exe`. The path to the driver`system32\odbcjt32.dll`reminded me of that.

Comment: You have raised very interesting and valuable points I did not think about concerning admin-rights. As concerns the 32 bit ODBC management, I noticed that the 32 bit datasource manager lists the Access  driver as an ODBC driver but the 64 bit datasource manager does not. That's why I stuck to my driver.

Comment: Changing ODBC_CONFIG_SYS_DSN to ODBC_CONFIG_DSN gets rid of the error. If I want to work on a system DSN I suppose I would need to run as administrator.